# How to use the LLVM library to write an assembler

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, arm, llvm

I want to write a simple assembler for x86/arm. Since implementing all instructions would be cumbersome, I figuered I could use the LLVM project **without using LLVM IR**.

[llvm-mc](http://blog.llvm.org/2010/04/intro-to-llvm-mc-project.html) seems to have exactly that feature:

```sh
$ echo "addl %eax, %ebx" | llvm-mc -show-encoding -show-inst
```

However I can't find any resources that explain how to use the MC in C++ code.
I woulde have expected something similar to:

```cpp
MCBuilder builder = X86::MCBuilder::create(rwx_memory_loc);
builder.AddInst("add", EAX, ECX);
builder.AddInst("mov", RAX, RDX);
...
```

As an alternative I propably would use [Module inline assembly](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#module-level-inline-assembly).

Comment: did this help ? https://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/

Comment: The LLVM project already implements an assembler using LLVM Machine Code so maybe just look at that.

Comment: @darune thank you for your comment but in this tutorial he does not generate Assembly but LLVM IR that is then run by the libs. I am looking for a hook into the low-level assembler, aka LLVM Machine Code (MC).

Comment: @RossRidge that is my guess. Do you happen to know any good resources, besides the LLVM doxygen and the actual source code?

Answer (score 1):

Assembler is a part of the backend. So, you'll probably want to take a look at `lib/Target/ARM` subdirectory. It is pretty complex piece of LLVM, but some guidance can be found [here](https://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html).

I suspect, you are interested in modifying/adding some asm instructions? Take a look at `*InstrInfo.td` file.

Comment: I like your answer, but it start to believe, that there is no simple way to achieve it without using LLVM IR.